# Combine Row information with Column headers to create one variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data along the lines of:

```
Person  Score1  Score2
A   1   4
B   2   5
C   3   6
```

The ultimate goal being to sort the combination of Person and Score from highest to lowest from all possible values in the original matrix

My thought is to create a dataset/variable using Python/Pandas that turn this into:

```
Person  Score
A-Score1    1
A-Score2    4
B-Score1    2
B-Score2    5
C-Score1    3
C-Score2    6
```

and then do a sort but not sure how to do this or if there is a better way?

Comment: `df.melt('Person')`

Comment: @Wen, i proposed  the answer :-) , this is what i got at the first point

Comment: @Alistair, pls see if the answer helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with `df.melt`

your required data:

```
>>> df
  Person  Score1  Score2
0      A       1       4
1      B       2       5
2      C       3       6
>>> pd.melt(df, id_vars=["Person"]).sort_values('Person')
  Person variable  value
0      A   Score1      1
3      A   Score2      4
1      B   Score1      2
4      B   Score2      5
2      C   Score1      3
5      C   Score2      6
```

OR

```
>>> df
  Person  Score1  Score2
0      A       1       4
1      B       2       5
2      C       3       6
>>>
>>>
>>> df.melt('Person')
  Person variable  value
0      A   Score1      1
1      B   Score1      2
2      C   Score1      3
3      A   Score2      4
4      B   Score2      5
5      C   Score2      6
```

## OR

```
>>> pd.melt(df, id_vars=['Person'], value_vars=['Score1', 'Score2'])
  Person variable  value
0      A   Score1      1
1      B   Score1      2
2      C   Score1      3
3      A   Score2      4
4      B   Score2      5
5      C   Score2      6
```